# The description of my equation is not coming on the same page

Tags: beamer, equations, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

```
\begin{frame}{Empirical specification}
 \vspace{-2cm}
 \begin{itemize}
     \item [] We employ the quasi-exogenous variation of an In-laws death
     \end{itemize}
     \vspace{-1cm}

 $$\medium{Y_{it}=\alpha_{i} + \omega_{dt} +\beta{{inlawdeath_{i}*post_{it}}}+\theta{post_{it}} +\rho{X_{it}}+\epsilon_{it}}$$
 

\begingroup
\RaggedRight
\text{\scriptsize{${Y_{it}}$ =Health outcome (BMI/IU) of women ${i}$ in survey round ${t}$ }}
\text{\scriptsize{${inlawdeath_{i}}$ =indicator equal to one if the DIL ${i}$’s 
PIL died }}
\text{\scriptsize{${post_{it}}$ = Indicator when considering data from wave 2}}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\text{\scriptsize{$\alpha_{i}$ = Individual Fixed Effects  }}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\text{\scriptsize{$\omega_{dt}$ = District Survey Fixed Effects}}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\text{\scriptsize{${X_{it}}$ = Time-varying controls}}
 \endgroup
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Why should they? `\text` outside math mode is just `\mbox`.

Comment: @egreg Ah, yes. Of course you are correct!

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to guess what `\medium` should mean. But you have several things that aren't necessary.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\medium}{???}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Empirical specification}

We employ the quasi-exogenous variation of an In-laws death
\[
\medium{
  Y_{it}=\alpha_{i} + \omega_{dt} +\beta\, inlawdeath_{i} \cdot post_{it}
  +\theta\,post_{it} +\rho X_{it}+\epsilon_{it}
}
\]

\begin{flushleft}\scriptsize

$Y_{it}$ = Health outcome (BMI/IU) of women ${i}$ in survey round ${t}$

$inlawdeath_{i}$ = indicator equal to one if the DIL ${i}$’s 
PIL died

$post_{it}$ = Indicator when considering data from wave 2

$\alpha_{i}$ = Individual Fixed Effects

$\omega_{dt}$ = District Survey Fixed Effects

$X_{it}$ = Time-varying controls

\end{flushleft}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that I removed *all* `\vspace` declarations and also `\RaggedRight` that serves no purpose, replacing it with `flushleft` with a `\scriptsize` declaration.

Note also the thin spaces `\,` when a long “variable name” is next to another symbol.

Never use `$$` in LaTeX. And refrain from useless braces.

[image]

The result is a bit cramped, though. Probably `\footnotesize` is better.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using an `align*` environment to list the variables' meanings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Empirical specification}
We employ a quasi-exogenous variation of an in-law's death:
\[
Y_{it} = \alpha_{i} + \omega_{dt} + \beta\,inlawdeath_{i}\cdot post_{it}
  + \theta\,post_{it} + \rho\,X_{it} + \epsilon_{it}
\]
where\small
\begin{align*}
Y_{it} &\quad \text{Health outcome (BMI/IU) of woman $i$ in survey round $t$} \\
inlawdeath_{i} &\quad \text{Indicator equal to 1 if DIL $i$'s PIL died} \\
post_{it} &\quad \text{Indicator when considering data from wave~2} \\
\alpha_{i} &\quad \text{Individual fixed effects}\\
\omega_{dt} &\quad \text{District survey fixed effects}\\
X_{it} &\quad \text{Time-varying controls}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```